# Validation plugin processing two forms at once, error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have built this plugin for jquery that does form validation on bootstrap styled forms. When I was using it the other day in development I discovered an error when I have it on two forms that are on the same page. When I try to submit one of the forms the validator script will validate both forms, and since an error occurs in the empty form neither will submit. So I am trying to figure why this is

**How it works**

`$.validator();` is the plugin. It takes in a series of options, documentation for which can be found here, https://github.com/MarkHill89/validator. When the plugin is initialized it initializes `keyup`, `change`, `select`, and `click` functionality for each type of input and the validator will validate as you go.

`$.validator.check()` is the return value the user calls for when you attempt to submit the form. This method returns a boolean value and nothing more.

My thought process on this is since the validator is attached to two separate forms shouldn't it only check those forms that it is attached to on initialization? I would think this would be true since when I do something like:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).validator.chek()){
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

then since it is being passed by reference to the attached object, and said object is the active element then the other form (this inactive object) shouldn't trigger at all, correct? This is my point of confusion.

**What I'm doing**

*javascript*

```
 $('#signupform').validator({
    notEmpty : ['#email_address', '#password', '#first_name', '#date_of_birth'],
    isDateTime : ['#date_of_birth'],
    isEmail : ['#email_address'],
    validPassword : ['#password'],

});
// submitting the sign-up form
$('#signupform').on('click', '.btn-primary', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').spin('large');
    if($('#signupform').validator.check()){
        var data = {
            callback : 'registerUser',
            parameters : {
                email_address : $('#email_address', this).val(),
                password : $('#password', this).val(),
                first_name : $('#first_name', this).val(),
                date_of_birth : $('#date_of_birth', this).val()
            }
        };
        $.ajax({
            url : "$APP_BASE/assets/server/callbacks.php",
            type : 'POST',
            data : data,
            dataType : "JSON",
            success : function(response){
                $('body').spin(false);
                if(!response.errors){
                    bootbox.alert(response.success_message);
                    $('#signupform')[0].reset();
                }else{
                    bootbox.alert(response.error_message);
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('body').spin(false);
    }
});

// validating the signin form
$('#signinform').validator({
    notEmpty : ['#signin_email_address', '#signin_password'],
    isEmail : ['#signin_email_address']
});

// submitting the sign-in form
$('#signinform').on('click', '.btn-primary', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#signinform').validator.check()){
        alert('good');
    }else{
        alert('bad');
    }
});
```

*html*

```
<section class='col-md-8'>
    <div class='row'>
        <article class='col-md-5'>
            <h4>Already a member? Sign-in!</h4>
            <div class='row'>
                <form id='signinform' action='' method='post'>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <input type='text' id='signin_email_address' class='form-control' placeholder='E-Mail Address' />
                    </article>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <input type='password' id='signin_password' class='form-control' placeholder='password' />
                    </article>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <button type='submit' form='signinform' class='btn btn-primary'>Sign-in</button>
                    </article>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article class='col-md-2' style='margin-top:50px'>
            <h4 class='text-center'> - or - </h4>
        </article>
        <article class='col-md-5'>
            <h4>Sign-Up for free, today!</h4>
            <div class='row'>
                <form id='signupform' action='' method='post'>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <input type='text' id='email_address' class='form-control' placeholder='E-Mail Address' />
                    </article>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <input type='password' id='password' class='form-control' placeholder='Password' />
                    </article>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <input type='text' id='first_name' class='form-control' placeholder='First Name' />
                    </article>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <input type='text' id='date_of_birth' class='form-control' placeholder='Date of Birth' />
                    </article>
                    <article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
                        <button type='submit' form='signupform' class='btn btn-primary'>Sign-Up</button>
                    </article>
                </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Summary**

Here is a working demo with the plugin code and the code from the examples above that shows the error in question being duplicated

http://jsfiddle.net/0991m63f/

To sum everything um, all I'm after here is a solution to why both forms are submitting at once, and how to fix it. I have been racking my brain over this for quite awhile and I"m lost. Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your function `$.fn.validator.check`

Since you have validator.check, you will be calling the check function on top of validator.

There for `this` will be equal to `function $.fn.validator()`, which is what you are sending to `Validator()`

Proposed changes include:
Changing the function to `$.fn.validatorCheck()`

or

```
$.fn.validator.check = function(context){
    var _data = null;
    var _mode = "check";
    var _Validator = new Validator(context, _mode, _data);
    _Validator.init();
    return _Validator.valid;
};
$.fn.validator.check($('#signupform').);
```